# Pygame: Creating a sprite with an irregular shape?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a survival game in pygame, Python 2.7. I am using a class oriented program but I don't know how to use `Surface` to make a tree. Is there a function that can create such an image?

Here is my code:

```
class Tree(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    global green
    global brown
    def __init__(self):
        super(Tree,self).__init__()
        self.image=pygame.Surface([20, 20])
        self.image.fill(green)
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
```

Comment: You can draw anything you like on the `self.image` `Surface` object, including blitting a `pygame.image` file to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surface allows you to draw and represent images on screen:
https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html
http://www.cogsci.rpi.edu/~destem/gamedev/pygame.pdf

I will update the answer once I have more info. What tree do you want to draw?
Can it be as simple as a green circle and a brown rectangle trunk under or you need an elaborate fractal image?

Here is code that will give you a Christmas tree:

```
def draw_a_tree(surface, leaf_size, (x,y), is_trunk=True):
    if is_trunk:
        rect = pygame.rect.Rect((x - 25, y - 30), (50,60))
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, (102,68,34), rect)
        draw_a_tree(surface, leaf_size, (x, y-30), False)
    elif leaf_size <= 2:
        return
    else:
        pygame.draw.polygon(surface, (0,200,0),((x-leaf_size/2,y),(x+leaf_size/2,y),(x,y-(2*leaf_size/3))))
        draw_a_tree(surface, 3*leaf_size/4, (x, y-leaf_size/3), False)
```

Source: http://helloworldbookblog.com/12-days-of-python-day-6/

Answer (score 0):

If you want a plain image of a tree, you can use blit:

```
image = pygame.image.load("tree.jpg")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
screen.blit(image, (x1, y1))
```